# How to send data from content.js to background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to send some data from my content.js to background script in my chrome extension. I tried `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` but it is undefined. It happens because of my manifest file where `world:MAIN` is set for content script. Here is the code for content.js

```
listenerFn = (event) => {
  const url = event.target.responseURL;
  if (url.startsWith("https://example.com/api/v2/home/allfeed")) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      type: "response",
      data: event.target.responseText,
    });
  }
};

(() => {
  let XHR = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
  let send = XHR.send;
  XHR.send = function () {
    this.addEventListener("load", listenerFn);
    return send.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "world": "MAIN"
    }
  ]
```

Is there a way of sending data from content script to background script.

Comment: The MAIN world is no longer a part of the extension, so you must either use `externally_connectable` messaging or add a second content script without `world` and use CustomEvent to relay the message.